# Browser compibility Issue on my website

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created website on jsp/servlet.
On that web site there is one function delete user on selected user. I'm not able to delete that function on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, but it's working fine on IE8.

[image: image for reference]

Comment: Any error on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below link. hope it'll help you :)

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3624446

[Cross-browser compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299799/cross-browser-compatibility-issues)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has also fine develop tools, but let's take Firefox:

Check first the JavaScript error console for any errors.

Install an HTML validator plugin.

If that helps not:

Install Firebug plugin to *develop*.

Install Tamperdata plugin to follow communication.